# ffmpeg trimming video giving extra seconds with no video/audio

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

There are a lot of questions about ffmpeg trimming but could found a related one.

I am trimming a video from time x to time x+30. What I do is

```
> ffmpeg -ss 127 -i test_video_2.mp4 -t 30 -c copy test_video_2_ssi_to.mp4

ffmpeg version 2.8.12 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101                                                                              libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[aac @ 0x655000] element type mismatch 1 != 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     :
    minor_version   :
    compatible_brands:
    encoder         :
  Duration: 00:17:59.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 436 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 365 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 6
0 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp4 @ 0x682a60] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
[mp4 @ 0x682a60] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers
Output #0, mp4, to 'test_video_2_ssi_to.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     :
    minor_version   :
    compatible_brands:
    encoder         :
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, 365 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k
tbn, 16k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:                                                                                                             handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1110 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1552kB time=00:00:30.01 bitrate= 423.7kbits/s
video:1227kB audio:289kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.351015%
```

The log says the output is 30s duration, but the output file is 37s, with the last 7 seconds having no more frames and audios. I suspect this might be related to keyframes but can't seem to debug.

```
> ffprobe test_video_2_ssi_to.mp4
ffprobe version 2.8.12 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[aac @ 0x641e40] element type mismatch 1 != 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test_video_2_ssi_to.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:37.04, start: -7.021333, bitrate: 343 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 271 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Same for other videos, making a few dummy seconds in the end.

Comment: I see that the trimmed video's start time is -7. Would this be the reason?

Comment: 2.8 is a very old version. Much has changed. Upgrade to latest (4.2.3)

Comment: I can confirm that I also see a similar thing happening in ffmpeg version `4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1`